# Using a Objective-C++ UIView Subclass within a UIViewController

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Good day,

I have currently started working on how to implement a live camera in a tableview... The blue block in the image is where the camera will appear...

[image]

I am using the Foscam and Hikvision Camera SDKs and I got it to work on the Foscam...

I am however stuck on the Hikvision due to a minor issue I need to overcome...

My main class for this tableview is a UIViewController (due to a custom layout) implemented is Objective-C (thus a .m for the implementation)(call this CamerasVC.m).

Hikvision however has a Objective-C++ SDK, which forced me to have a .mm implementation... When I try to implement the Hikvision subclass (call it HikvisionCameraPreview.mm) in the CamerasVC, I receive a lot of errors pertaining to the Objective-C++ vs Objective-C within the Hikvision Library...

Code Used to try this in the CamerasVC.m:

```
#import "HikvisionCameraPreview.h"
#import "HikvisionCameraPreview.h"

@interface CamerasVC ()
@end

@implementation CamerasVC

//code omitted 

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    //code omitted 
    if ([[((ObjectCameras*)[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).processName uppercaseString] isEqual:[@"HikVision" uppercaseString]])
    {
        //HIKVISION - this causes much errors
        HikvisionCameraPreview *thisMiniView = [[HikvisionCameraPreview alloc]initWithFrame:vidView.frame];
        [thisMiniView setSelectedCamera:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [vidView addSubview:thisMiniView];
    }
    else
    {
        //FOSCAM - which is working
        FosCamCameraPreview *thisMiniView = [[FosCamCameraPreview alloc]initWithFrame:vidView.frame];
        [thisMiniView setSelectedCamera:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [vidView addSubview:thisMiniView];
    }
}

//code omitted 
@end
```

My question: Is there any way to implement the .mm implementation within a .m implementation file?

Comment: you should convert any .m file that will use .mm  to ..mm also

Comment: would a .m file still function normally when implemented in a .mm file?

Comment: yes will have no problem , just check

Comment: Thank you will try it quickly